# How to find element using UIAutomator in appium

Tags: android, appium, android-uiautomator

I am testing android hybrid application using appium. Could anyone please tell me how to find element using UIAutomator because xpath given by appium doesn't work in my case.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have my app under the test on real device (but it can be on Emulator as well) connected to my desktop and run it, open some screen/page. Than I run uiautomatorviewer.bat as Administrator (strange, but I have to run it as Administrator). Than I click Device Screenshot icon on the left top corner of UI Automator Viewer and I can see the screenshot and Android classes on the right pane. I can navigate, click different elements and observe their hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Do View above the Terms link and ListView have resource-id or text attributes?

I think you can try something like the following:

```
xpath="(//android.widget.ListView[contains(@resource-id,'some_id')]//android.widget.View)[2]/android.widget.View"
```

Try to find the node and then create relative path to the child.

```
// - means any after (any child)
/ - goes immediate after
[2] - the second item that corresponds the criteria
```

if you know the text attribute's value, you may use something like:    `[contains(@text, 'some part of text')]`

Comment: No, it doesn't have resource-id or text attributes. But Terms link view is having content-desc. So I have used 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[@content-desc='Terms Link']")).click();
Now, my test case passes but on device there is no click executed. Should I use android.widget.View instead of android.view.View?

Comment: no, as I see the android.view.View has attribute clickable = true. Try to count how many elements that meet the criteria you have on the screen.      `List<WebElement> elements =
   driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.view.View[@content-desc='Terms Link']"));
   System.out.println(elements.size());`

Comment: also, I would recommend to set on your Android device settings (Developers) to show touches and taps in order to see where Appium script clicks exactly

Comment: it works for elements which are displayed on screen but not for elements which are displayed after scrolling.

Comment: yes, you get what you see, the same way the Appium does. It cannot count what it can't see.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
driver.findElementsByXPath("//*[@class='android.view.View' and @index='0']");
```

Comment: make sure to change the class name and index as per you need.

Comment: Thanks, this works for elements which are currently displayed on device screen but for elements which are displayed after scroll, doesn't work for them although my test case results in pass even without seeing actual click on device screen.

Comment: @Suman it should be pretty simply. Just find the x and y coordinates and scroll to it. And then by using same approach i mentioned above click on the element

Answer (score 0):

Follow this approach to get the attributec ('contentDescription') from any element using UIautomator -

```
self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('SomeAccessibilityID').get_attribute('contentDescription')
```